# Laravel 5.7: On-Demand e-mail Notification via AWS SES treats my recipient e-mail as a sender e-mail and wants it to be verified address

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I want to send a simple [on-demand e-mail notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#on-demand-notifications) in Laravel 5.7.

I went to AWS SES and under Email Addresses I added `do-not-reply@foo` as a sender. Then I click on the verification link on `do-not-reply@foo` to confirm it.

[image]

I configured my `.env`:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=do-not-reply@foo
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Foo System"
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I took username and password from here:

[image]

I did `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`.

Now in terms of my PHP code I have:

```
$this->notificationClass = (new ReflectionClass($notificationClass))->getShortName();
$this->notificationData = $notificationData;
$this->notification
    ->route('slack', config('logging.channels.slack.url')) // slack works great all the time
    ->route('mail', 'my-inbox-address-123@gmail.com') // this is address where I want notification to be sent
    ->notify(new $notificationClass(
        $this->getNotificationTitle(),
        $this->getNotificationContent()
    ));
```

And the content of `$notificationClass` is:

````
<?php

namespace App\Notifications\Sync;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\SlackMessage;

class SyncSuccessfullyCompletedNotification extends AbstractBaseSyncNotification
{
    public function toSlack()
    {
        return (new SlackMessage)
            ->success()
            ->content(sprintf('*Synchronization Successful*```%s```', $this->message));
    }

    public function toMail()
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
            ->subject($this->title)
            ->view('mail.notifications.sync_successfully_completed_notification', [
                'content' => sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>', $this->message),
            ]);
    }
}
````

So `my-inbox-address-123@gmail.com` is just my gmail company inbox. When I execute the artisan command responsible for doing something and sending this notification I get:

> Swift_TransportException  : Expected response code 250 but got code
>   "554", with message "554 Message rejected: Email address is not
>   verified. The following identities failed the check in region
>   US-WEST-2: my-inbox-address-123@gmail.com "
>
> at
>   /home/vagrant/Code/iosportal/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:457
>       453|             $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchEvent($evt, 'responseReceived');
>       454|         }
>       455|
>       456|         if (!$valid) {
>
> > 457|             $this->throwException(new Swift_TransportException('Expected response code '.implode('/',
> >     $wanted).' but got code "'.$code.'", with message "'.$response.'"',
> >     $code));
> >         458|         }
> >         459|     }
> >         460|
> >         461|     /** Get an entire multi-line response using its sequence number */
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport::assertResponseCode("554
>   Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following
>   identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2:
>   my-inbox-address-123@gmail.com ")
>         /home/vagrant/Code/iosportal/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:341
>
> 2   Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport::executeCommand(" . ", [])
>         /home/vagrant/Code/iosportal/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php:305
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Why? I don't get this. My sender is verified, why it wants to verify a recipient?

Indeed when I send this message from verified account to the same verified account the email arrives correctly, but this is nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your account must be in `sandbox` mode, which means every email address has to be verified.

**Check if you are in sandbox mode:**

1. Sign in to the [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/).
2. Select your region.
3. Under Email Sending choose Sending Statistics.
4. If you are in sandbox mode you will see a banner telling you so.

**To get out of sandbox mode:**

1. Sign in to the [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/).
2. Open an [SES Sending Limit Increase](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest/) case in Support Center.
3. Complete the form. If you plan to send from more than one region, repeat for each region.

Comment: Thank you John. I've raised a ticket with AWS support and they turned the sandbox mode off. Everything works. 